# How to filter NSArray using two NSPredcates

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, nspredicate

I would like to filter an NSArray of NSDictionaries, however I would like to filter the result using one, two or even three NSPredicate values?

Currently I am filtering my array by doing this.

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parts == %@", filterString];//keySelected is NSString itself
        NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[currentParts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateString]];
        sortedItemsArray = [filteredArray mutableCopy];
```

But I am not sure how I would do this using two predicates?

The other two predicates individually look like the one above accept different keys.

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"area == %@", filterString];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item == %@", filterString];
```

What I was thinking is that maybe you could have something like

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stage == %@ area == %@", filterString, areaflterstring];
```

But I don't think that's possible.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10611362/457406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to tell the predicate how to combine the parts, like:

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stage == %@ AND area == %@", filterString, areaflterstring];
```

You can alternatively use `NSCompoundPredicate` to combine a number of predicates.

Comment: awesome thankyou very much. will research NSCompoundPredicate now :)